# Retrive a Xcomm value and pass it to spark _steps in EMR operator, Airflow

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am trying to retrieve value from a python operator and pass it to "EMR create job"  and "add steps operator". How do I pass this value in spark_steps,
I have used task_instance to access it but it didn't work, can someone please tell me how to access this?

Error:

NameError: name 'task_instance' is not defined

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.models.connection import Connection
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_add_steps import EmrAddStepsOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_create_job_flow import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_terminate_job_flow_operator import EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr_step import EmrStepSensor
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
import boto3
from airflow.providers.slack.operators.slack_webhook import SlackWebhookOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
import pendulum
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import json, os
import pytz
from airflow.models import Variable



os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']="11111"
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']="111111"
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']='us-west-1'
account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')


def get_secret():
    print("started")

    secret_name =  Variable.get("secret_name")
    region_name = Variable.get("region_name")

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name=region_name)
    account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
    
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret_str = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            secret=json.loads(secret_str)            
            airflow_path=secret["airflow_path"]
            return airflow_path 

    except Exception as e:
        print("AWS Exception raised :" +e)
        raise
local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Chicago")
DAG_ID = os.path.basename(__file__).replace(".py", "")
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-west-1'



DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'Sam Kurth',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['aa@12.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
              }

SPARK_STEPS = [
       
    {
        'Name': 'Spark-Submit Command',
        "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
                'spark-submit',
                '--py-files',
                's3://'+{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_aws_fields', key='return_value') }}+'-pyspark/hell/config.zip,s3://'+{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_aws_fields', key='return_value') }}+'-pyspark/hell/jobs.zip,s3://'+path+'-pyspark/hell/DDL.zip',
                's3://'+path+'-pyspark/hell/main.py'
                    ],
                        },
    },

    {
        'Name': 'Copy Test Scripts',
        "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": ["aws","s3","cp","s3://"+{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_aws_fields', key='return_value') }}+"-pyspark/hell/run_test.sh","/home/hadoop/"],
        }
    },


    {
        'Name': 'Execute Test Scripts',
        "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": ["sh","/home/hadoop/run_test.sh"],
                        }
    }
            ]


JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    "Name": "Hell ETL",
    "LogUri": "s3://aws-logs-559293306438-us-west-1/elasticmapreduce/",
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-6.2.0",
    "Applications": [
        {
            "Name": "Spark"
        },
    ],
    "Instances": {
       "Ec2SubnetId": "subnet-0d626501d9db34925",
        "InstanceGroups": [
            {
                "Name": "Master nodes",
                "Market": "ON_DEMAND",
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
                "InstanceCount": 1,
            }
        ],
        "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": False,
        "TerminationProtected": False,

    },

    "BootstrapActions": [
        {
            "Name": "Install Dependencies",
            "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
                "Path": "s3://"+path+"-pyspark/hell/install_python_modules.sh",
            }
        }

    ],
    
}


with DAG(
        dag_id=DAG_ID,
        description='Run built-in Spark app on Amazon EMR',
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
        start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 4, 19,tz=local_tz),
        schedule_interval='05 7 * * *',      
        tags=['emr-dev'],
) as dag:

    get_aws_secret=[PythonOperator(task_id='get_aws_fields',python_callable=get_secret)]
    cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(ti,task_id='create_job_flow',job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES)
    step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(task_id='add_steps',job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
                                     aws_conn_id='aws_default',steps=SPARK_STEPS, )
    step_checker = EmrStepSensor(task_id='watch_step',job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
                                step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='add_steps', key='return_value')[0] }}",aws_conn_id='aws_default',) 

    get_aws_secret>>cluster_creator >> step_adder >> step_checker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{ task_instance }}` in your `SPARK_STEPS` is not contained in a string.

```
's3://'+{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_aws_fields', key='return_value') }}+'-pyspark/hell/config.zip,s3://'+{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_aws_fields', key='return_value') }}+'-pyspark/hell/jobs.zip,s3://'+path+'-pyspark/hell/DDL.zip',
```

Should be

```
's3://'+"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_aws_fields', key='return_value') }}"+'-pyspark/hell/config.zip,s3://'+"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_aws_fields', key='return_value') }}"+'-pyspark/hell/jobs.zip,s3://'+path+'-pyspark/hell/DDL.zip',
```

Also looks like `path` in `'s3://'+path+'-pyspark/hell/main.py'` isn't defined in the DAG either.